# My code Catalan number in C is not working ( using recurrence formula )

Tags: c, arrays, recurrence, catalan

I am trying to insert all Catalan number in array, but my code is not working.

- Description: Insert the elements in the Catalan sequence in the array given initialized only for C[0].
- Inputs: address of array

  - n: next position to be filled;
  - top: maximum number of entries to be computed.
- Output:

  - int: number of elements in the array.
  - Side effects: update the elements of the array.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define MAX 6
int CatSeq (int CatArray[], int n, int top){
    int c;
    if (top == 1) CatArray[n]= 1; 
    else{ 
        for ( c = 0; c <= MAX; c++){
            CatArray[n] = 2 * (2*top - 1) * CatSeq(CatArray, n, top-1) / (top+1);
            n++;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
void PrintSeq(int Seq[], int top){
    int i; 
    for ( i = 1; i < MAX; i++)  
        printf("%d \n", Seq[i]);
}
int main(){
    int c = 0, n = 0 ;
    int CatArray[MAX];
    c = CatSeq(CatArray, n, MAX);
    PrintSeq(CatArray, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "my code is not working" mean? Is it segfaulting? Not producing what you expect?

Comment: Also, I imagine the `for` loop in your `PrintSeq` function should start off `i = 0`, not `i = 1`

Comment: [Here](http://www.calcul.com/catalan-recursive) is an alternative method for computing catalan numbers, which doesn't involve division, and might be a bit simpler to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Array out of index error:

```
for ( c = 0 ; c <= MAX;c++){
                ^
                check loop
```

Correct is:

```
for ( n = 0 ; n < MAX; n++){
```

it should be `n < MAX`, since n could be passed in as non-zero to the function.

```
CatArray[n] = 2 * (2*top - 1) * CatSeq(CatArray, n, top-1) / (top+1);
                                                 ^
                                                here n is non-zero
```

no need of `c` variable.

Comment: `c` is not used as an index (could be a typo in OP's code though)

Comment: @DrewMcGowen `n` is used that is incremented on each iteration

Comment: In that case, it should be `n < MAX`, since `n` could be passed in as non-zero to the function.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Thanks corrected check again! I said you beat me normally  :)